# Нужна ли запятая

Tags: пунктуация

Во время разговора не допускать, чтобы учитель сидел, а родитель стоял(,) или чтобы учитель сидел за своим столом, а родитель — за ученическим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во время разговора не допускать, чтобы учитель сидел, а родитель стоял или чтобы учитель сидел за своим столом, а родитель — за ученическим. Запятая перед "или" не нужна, так это предложение сложноподчиненное с однородными придаточными предложениями. При наличии между ними соединительных или разделительных союзов запятая не ставится

Answer (score 0):

Нужда, конечно. Ведь тут законченный оборот (прошу прощения, не силен в терминологии) "чтобы учитель сидел, а родитель стоял".

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что месье Szael прав. Синтаксическая конструкция "а родитель стоял" - простое предложение, связанное с предложением "чтобы учитель сидел" сочинительной связью. Необходимо обозначить границы этого предложения, и с этой задачей как нельзя лучше справляется запятая.

Comment: Думаю,что запятая не нужна, потому что "старшей структурой" является СПП с двумя придаточными частями: "нельзя  допускать, чтобы() или чтобы()". Именно эту структуру надо обязательно обозначить отсутствием запятой.В то же время придаточные части - это ССП, но это уже "внутренние" структуры.

Comment: Мда-а... неплохо было бы иметь под рукой ссылку на источник, регламентирующий пунктуационное оформление в таких случаях, не то, доверившись интуиции автора, мы скоро вообще перестанем обращать внимание на существующий регламент.

Comment: Думаю, что запятая здесь не авторский, а ОСНОВНОЙ знак (в случае авторских знаков возможны оба варианта). А чтобы доказать правильность решения, можно привести следующий пример: "Через час явилась возможность ехать: метель утихла и небо прояснилось". Здесь мы видим, что "старшей" связью является бессоюзная связь, поэтому запятая между предложениями при наличии сочинительного союза И не ставится. Этот вариант вполне легитимный, на него можно ссылаться.

Comment: Да, это подходящая аналогия, я о ней забыла, прошу прощения.